# lua_register using const char * actionname, void(*action)()

Tags: c++, lua

I have a `lua_State` ready to go with a script that will call `actionname`.
Before the script is started an `void(*action)()` needs to be registered. This process is called by a client that does not have access to my `lua_State` nor does the client include lua. I can not change method signature to `lua_CFunction` because the client code will not know the definitions needet to provide that function.

I have to provide a function like this one here:

```
void registeraction(const char * actionname, void(*action)())
{
    struct functor
    {
        void(*action)();
        functor(void(*action)()) : action(action) {}
        int operator()(lua_State* state) { action(); return 0; }
    };
    functor callme{ action };
    lua_State * L = lua->ptr;
    const char * n = actionname;
    lua_CFunction f{ callme }; //no suitable conversion
    lua_register(L, n, f);
}
```

How can i wrap the action so I can shove it into Lua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward way is to give Lua a C closure.

You'll need one static function that act as dispatcher. When you register new action, you push new C closure, setting user-supplied function as upvalue for a closure.

When Lua call it, you will read pointer from upvalue and call that function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lua.hpp>

typedef void(*Action)();

// user actions
void some_action()
{
    printf("Must act\n");
}

void other_action()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
}

lua_State* L;
static int action_dispatcher(lua_State* L);

// this function will be exposed to users
void register_action(const char* name, Action act)
{
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void*)act);
    lua_pushcclosure(L, &action_dispatcher, 1);
    lua_setglobal(L, name);
}

int action_dispatcher(lua_State* L)
{
    Action action = (Action) lua_topointer(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
    if(action) action();
    return 0;
}

// test it
int main()
{
    L = luaL_newstate();

    // register actions
    register_action("act", &some_action);
    register_action("world", &other_action);

    // "run" script that will call registered actions
    luaL_dostring(L, "act() world()");
    lua_close(L);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```